# Compiling Android scource code on ubuntu 9.10

Tags: android

I have downloaded the android source code (1.5 Gb and appx. 5 Gb after extracting).My intention is to compile this.
1) Do i need a toolchain for arm ..if yes which one will be suitable.
2) to run simulator and to be able to debug on workstation do i need to have any specific PC -linux toolchain .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) http://source.android.com/source/download.html explains building the code for the Android Open Source project.
2) http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html explains how to debug the emulator using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

for compiling on Ubuntu 9.10, you also have to watch out the version of tool chain, ex. python, java.